# Local IIS 7 Returns 500 Error. Can't get details

Tags: iis-7

I have tried all of the solution out there and have resolved nothing. It's a MVC 4 site on IIS 7 that I'm tryuing to get set up. Local browsing of the site won't display detail error information. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

So far I have done...

1. Checked MachineConfig for  for .net 4 both 32 and 64 bit. It was not there so it shouldn't interfere.
2. Set customErrors mode="Off" in all config files.
3. Changed settings for DefaultErrorPages in the Site Settings to always display details.
4. Conducted an IISReset
5. Enabled failed request logging. Nothing was logged.
6. Checked the site error logs.=. Nothing indicated an error.
7. Checked Windows Logs. No errors logged under the IIS section.
8. Checked that the App Pool was running under .Net 4 and that it was set to integrated mode.
9. Turned off friendly errors in the setting for the browser

PS this is a production web server running Windows 2008R2 and IIS 7.0

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: IE9. I also turned off friendly errors in the setting for the browser

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion.

Comment: I just noticed that FF was loaded here so I tried it and got the same standard 500 message

Comment: I've had this issue in the past .. loading up some of my solutions to see how I modified the web.config.

Comment: 500 aside, you've stepped through your controller action and it's returning a proper view and model?

Comment: can you post the relevant section of your web.config (dealing with custom errors)

Comment: Well. It's running just fine on the development web server. I had to complete the setup there because the developer just moved the code from another offshore environment. I had hoped the set up in production environment would have been as easy.

Comment: the system.web is quite extensive but here is the node in question <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">

Comment: this is also set, correct? <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

Comment: Sorry yes that's there also

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I can offer without actually seeing the server. Good luck. These things can be frustrating, maybe something will click in tomorrow morning.

Comment: No problem, if I think of something I'll toss a comment up here unless you or someone else figures it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. One of the system admins had cloned the original production site intending for it to be used for the production beta, which was what I was setting up. Of course there was no communication as to what was needed to be kept in the copied site. Well it turns out there was a web.config in the original code that was doing a redirect to another location. Thus none of the new site configs were even being accessed. I removed all of the old code and it started working.